# Getting Error on "Negate" module in Unity 3D Visual Scripting tutorial "Clive the Cat"

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting

I am trying to program the script for the trap door lever in the fourth room.  The lever is supposed to start in the "on" position and when Clive enters the cell, it is supposed to switch to off, and the trap door "closes."  I am being instructed to use the "Negate"module for this tutorial, but I am getting the following error message:

InvalidConversionException: Cannot convert from 'System.Boolean' to 'UnityEngine.GameObject'.

Here is my script:

[image]

I cannot get it to close the trap door.  I have tried changing the data type, removing the trap door object and re-inserting and I have not found any useful documentation out there.  Thanks in advance.